# Cannot read property 'children' of null at object.Iscroll

Tags: iscroll

I know this question was asked before but those answers are not helpful to me.Here i'm using iscroll, i get this console error "Cannot read property 'children' of null at object.Iscroll" when reloading page. Can anyone help me.

```
function IScroll (el, options) {
    this.wrapper = typeof el == 'string' ? document.querySelector(el) : el;
    this.scroller = this.wrapper.children[0];
    this.scrollerStyle = this.scroller.style;       // cache style for better performance

    this.options = {

        resizeScrollbars: true,

        mouseWheelSpeed: 20,

        snapThreshold: 0.334,

// INSERT POINT: OPTIONS 

        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        scrollY: true,
        directionLockThreshold: 5,
        momentum: true,

        bounce: true,
        bounceTime: 600,
        bounceEasing: '',

        preventDefault: true,
        preventDefaultException: { tagName: /^(INPUT|TEXTAREA|BUTTON|SELECT)$/ },

        HWCompositing: true,
        useTransition: true,
        useTransform: true
    };

    for ( var i in options ) {
        this.options[i] = options[i];
    }

    // Normalize options
    this.translateZ = this.options.HWCompositing && utils.hasPerspective ? ' translateZ(0)' : '';

    this.options.useTransition = utils.hasTransition && this.options.useTransition;
    this.options.useTransform = utils.hasTransform && this.options.useTransform;

    this.options.eventPassthrough = this.options.eventPassthrough === true ? 'vertical' : this.options.eventPassthrough;
    this.options.preventDefault = !this.options.eventPassthrough && this.options.preventDefault;

    // If you want eventPassthrough I have to lock one of the axes
    this.options.scrollY = this.options.eventPassthrough == 'vertical' ? false : this.options.scrollY;
    this.options.scrollX = this.options.eventPassthrough == 'horizontal' ? false : this.options.scrollX;

    // With eventPassthrough we also need lockDirection mechanism
    this.options.freeScroll = this.options.freeScroll && !this.options.eventPassthrough;
    this.options.directionLockThreshold = this.options.eventPassthrough ? 0 : this.options.directionLockThreshold;

    this.options.bounceEasing = typeof this.options.bounceEasing == 'string' ? utils.ease[this.options.bounceEasing] || utils.ease.circular : this.options.bounceEasing;

    this.options.resizePolling = this.options.resizePolling === undefined ? 60 : this.options.resizePolling;

    if ( this.options.tap === true ) {
        this.options.tap = 'tap';
    }

    if ( this.options.shrinkScrollbars == 'scale' ) {
        this.options.useTransition = false;
    }

    this.options.invertWheelDirection = this.options.invertWheelDirection ? -1 : 1;

// INSERT POINT: NORMALIZATION

    // Some defaults    
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.directionX = 0;
    this.directionY = 0;
    this._events = {};

// INSERT POINT: DEFAULTS

    this._init();
    this.refresh();

    this.scrollTo(this.options.startX, this.options.startY);
    this.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is fixed, some undefined value stored in my 'el',i fix it, now it is working fine, Thanks for your views.